# How to imitate the functionality of Drop down to list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although, there is a similar question posted on StackOverflow but that doesn't solve my issue. So I have a drop down whose  options perform some action as it gets change, basically,  they submit a form and change the data accordingly. Here is sample code to display the drop down

```
<select class="select" onchange="submitData()"  id="Filter">
  <option value="-1" selected="">Items</option>
  <option value="0">Unread</option>
  <option value="1">Read</option>
</select>
```

And this is the function which get calls on when we change the item from drop down.

```
<script>
  submitData = function () {document.formHeader.submit();}
</script>
```

In "formHeader", there is a form coming for displaying data. And when I change the items in the drop down data get changes accordingly So Basically I want to convert the submitData functionality over a list. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: can you explain your question to me? i dont understand what you want to do here

Answer (score 1):

Use change event

```
<select class="select" id="Filter">
  <option value="-1" selected="">Items</option>
  <option value="0">Unread</option>
  <option value="1">Read</option>
</select>
```

On change get value and decide which form you want to submit

```
$("#Filter").change(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == -1)
  {
    $( "#ItemForm" ).submit();
  }
  else if(var == 0)
  {
    $( "#UnreadForm" ).submit();
  }
  else
  {
    $( "#ReadForm" ).submit();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you

Using list

```
<ul>
  <li class="filter" data-form="ItemForm">Items</li>
  <li class="filter" data-form="UnreadForm">Unread</li>
  <li class="filter" data-form="ReadForm">Read</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.filter').click(function(){
      var form = $(this).data('form');
      $('#'+form).submit();
    })  
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I want to change the drop down into list and then perform the same functionality

Comment: well, thanks for your answer but I have found a solution to my problem.